# Play framework dependencies: require list not found

Tags: playframework, migrate

I installed migrate-1.4 for play 1.2.5 and I add 
require:

- play -> migrate 1.4

in `dependencies.yml`.

After that, I run play dependencies which tells:

```
Oops, malformed dependencies.yml descriptor:
~
~       require list not found -> {require=play -> migrate 1.4}
~
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Malformed dependencies.yml descriptor
        at play.deps.YamlParser.parseDescriptor(YamlParser.java:204)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:185)
        at play.deps.DependenciesManager.resolve(DependenciesManager.java:341)
        at play.deps.DependenciesManager.main(DependenciesManager.java:39)
```

Who can tell me why?
Thanks a lot!

---

I made a stupid mistake! I actually added these in PLAY_HOME/framework/dependencies.yml which should be the one in my application's conf folder. After I added the dependencies, the dependencies.yml is like this:

```
# Application dependencies
require:
 - play -> table 1.2.1
 - play -> migrate 1.4
 - play -> search 2.0
 - play -> jersey 0.1
```

Then I run "play dependencies", the result is different.

```
 *****************************************************************************
 WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not work properly (use --verbose for details),

   play->jersey 0.1
   play->migrate 1.4
   play->table 1.2.1
   play->search 2.0
 *****************************************************************************

 Some dependencies are still missing.
```

Comment: Paste in your `dependencies.yml`. The key message here is `Malformed dependencies.yml descriptor` I reckon.

Comment: @maksimov The whole dependencies.yml is too long. I just give the related piece.  
require:  
    - play -> table 1.2.1  
require:  
    - play -> search 2.0  
require:  
    - play -> migrate 1.4  
require:  
    - play -> jersey 0.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have too many `require:`. Try changing your `dependencies.yml` like this:

```
require:
    - play -> table 1.2.1
    - play -> search 2.0
    - play -> migrate 1.4
    - play -> jersey 0.1
```

I.e. there should only be one `require:` section.

Comment: Thank you for your suggesttion! I tried but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: So like I said, you have two `require` sections now. Can you move your stuff from the bottom `require` to the top `require` and get rid of the bottom `require:` altogether?